# MS Excel sorting formula

Tags: excel-formula

Microsoft money used to be a brilliant programme for keeping track of a pension portfolio in that it showed value change weekly, monthly, 3 monthly and year to date, now it is no longer supported I have been trying to find an alternative. I now have an I Mac with MS excel on but am trying to do a sort and display on the following and try keep track as per MS Money did.
[Sample][1]
This data is updated weekly and would like to know if it is possible to replicate MS Money.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLahL.png

Comment: replicate MS Money in what way (every way or just the sort and display functionality?)

Answer (score 0):

ok so lets try the things you said about and see if we can get you close:

name the ranges ([link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64)) dates and values

weekly movement (current value / value 1 week ago):

```
=SUMIF(dates,MAX(dates),values)/SUMIF(dates,MAX(dates)-7,values)
```

1 month movement:

```
=SUMIF(dates,MAX(dates),values)/SUMIF(dates,MAX(dates)-ROUND((MAX(dates)-EDATE(MAX(dates),-1))/7,0)*7,values)
```

3 month movement:

```
=SUMIF(dates,MAX(dates),values)/SUMIF(dates,MAX(dates)-ROUND((MAX(dates)-EDATE(MAX(dates),-3))/7,0)*7,values)
```

ytd:

```
=SUMIF(dates,MAX(dates),values)/SUMIF(dates,MAX(dates)-ROUND((MAX(dates)-DATE(YEAR(MAX(dates)),1,1))/7,0)*7,values)
```

this assumes those named ranges and that the date is exactly every 7 days apart.  if also looks for the closest date to 1 month ago, 3 months ago and start of year.

also it does a current value as percentage of the start value for the period